# Can a Monk throw 2 Daggers (1 in each hand) and gain martial arts bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

Monks can use daggers as monk weapons, that part makes sense and is clear. Also, a character can dual wield daggers and thrown them both if they use action + bonus action.

But as daggers benefits from the specific martial arts bonus rule (You can use Dexterity instead of Strength for the **attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.)** Does that mean the monk will get bonuses to both attacks just as if they were to attack with 2 different unarmed strikes? Important to remember that the book states Specific Beats General as stated:

> This book contains rules, especially in parts 2 and 3, that govern how the game plays. That said, many racial traits, class features, spells, magic items, monster abilities,
>   and other game elements break the general rules in some way, creating an exception to how the rest of the game works. **Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.**

Comment: It's worth noting that if a monk has the Extra Attack feature, and uses that instead of TWF, they can throw both daggers and get their bonus to damage on both attacks. I believe they would also still be able to use their bonus action to perform Flurry of Blows.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, the 2nd attack won't get a bonus to damage.

The Monk's Martial Arts feature says:

> You can use Dexterity **instead of** Strength for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.

So, in effect, this allows you to switch Strength bonuses to attack and damage rolls to being Dexterity bonuses to attack and damage rolls. However, the two weapon fighting rule says:

> You don’t
>   add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.

So when using two weapon fighting, you don't *have* a bonus to your damage roll. If there was one, and it was Strength, Martial Arts would allow you to change it into Dexterity. But Martial Arts doesn't let you create a bonus to damage that doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

If you are using your bonus action to attack with your off-hand dagger, even though it is a monk weapon, you are using the dual-wielding rules which do not allow you to add anything as a modifier to damage, barring any feats or other features you may have.

Martial Arts only allows you to make an unarmed attack as a bonus action:

> When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon on your turn, **you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.**

It does not allow you to make an attack with another monk weapon.

Note that the dual-wielding rules are the ones that are specifically denying you the ability to add your modifier to damage here. Normally you are allowed to add them on every attack, but the dual-wielding rules specifically override that, hence why you can add your modifier to the Martial Arts bonus action attacks.

Comment: That is only 1 of multiple bonuses from Martial Arts. So with that said, why does the 2nd unarmed strike get the bonus damage and attack?

Comment: Added some info on why your Martial Arts attack gets a bonus but dual-wielding doesn't, hopefully that clears it up